# How to use web module of Python in Eclipse for HTTP server

Tags: windows, eclipse, http, python-2.7, web

I want to build simple http server in python that listens to TCP port and shows some html page form when accessed by the web browser (via HTTP GET request). And the user can put some data on the form via HTTP POST.

I am using Eclipse and Pydev.
I tried to use Web module

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import web 

urls = (
   '/', 'Index'
)
pytest = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

Error message is 
app = web.application(urls, globals())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'application'

I would appriciate if there is some other technique to do so aswell.

Comment: what is the 'web' module that you import -- where does it come form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using http://webpy.org

I tried to run your app:

```
$ pip install web.py
Downloading/unpacking web.py
  Downloading web.py-0.37.tar.gz (90kB): 90kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package web.py

Installing collected packages: web.py
  Running setup.py install for web.py

Successfully installed web.py
Cleaning up...
```

running yor code shows a problem:

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    app.run()
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

When I replace `app.run()` with `pytest.run()`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.run()
```

Everything works fine:

```
$ python test.py 
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

If you run this form within eclipse and your are using a virtualenv,
them make sure that you add the virtualenv (bin/python) to the

```
Preferences...>PyDev->Interpreter - Python
```

And in your launch config, use this envirtonment.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael..This hhelped me alot !!